# would using useState(undefined) for boolean state instead of useState(false\true) considered ok?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I am writing my program and I see almost everywhere, that the starting useState() condition is false: "**useState(false)**", when we are working with booleans.

But can I leave it empty (**useState()**), instead of defining it as false?
In my example, I am defining 3 states for error messages:

```
  const [isErrorInName, setIsErrorInName] = useState();
  const [isErrorInEmail, setIsErrorInEmail] = useState();
  const [isErrorInMessage, setIsErrorInMessage] = useState();
```

And below I use useEffect hook:

```
  useEffect(() => {
   if (
     isErrorInName === false &&
     isErrorInEmail === false &&
     isErrorInMessage === false
   ) {
        document.getElementById("contact-form").reset();
     }
   }, [isErrorInName, isErrorInEmail, isErrorInMessage]);
```

And because of this hook I can't define these useState() conditions as false, because then the form will be reseted, when the app will start, because this is what useEffect hook does. But if I leave them as undefined, everything is working.

Thanks!

Comment: what is the question? whether that's ok?

Comment: yes, because everywhere, where I searched, I saw only useState(false), but nowhere useState(undefined)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

Also, instead, you can also add the state isPrestine, to indicate no input is entered:

```
const [isPrestine, setIsFormPrestine] = useState(true);
```

That way, each variable represents a single thing, which might improve code in the long run.

```
  const [isErrorInName, setIsErrorInName] = useState(false);
  const [isErrorInEmail, setIsErrorInEmail] = useState(false);
  // and so forth

  if (
 ! isPrestine &&
 ! isErrorInName &&
 ! isErrorInEmail &&
 ! isErrorInMessage 
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, AFAIK there isn't a problem with an empty `useState`, so it is something you can do.
If, on the other hand, you do want it to contain an initial value, it's possible to detect first render in a few ways, like [this one](https://medium.com/anna-coding/the-way-to-check-if-its-the-first-time-for-useeffect-function-is-being-run-in-react-hooks-170520554067), where a `ref` is being used solely for this purpose.

P.S. - would recommend to conjoin states like these into objects to prevent pointless re-renders.
Especially useful when you are dealing with a bunch of different state pieces.

i.e:

```js
const [errors, setErrors] = useState({
   isErrorInName: false,
   isErrorInEmail: false,
   isErrorInMessage: false,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You most certainly can. However, for these types of situations, I usually prefer to set the initial value to null.

This has a couple of advantages, for instance, you can define the type for your hooks (i.e: `useState<boolean>(null)` is very much ok) and you can check whether it has been set or not using `=== null` and you can reset it back to null if you need to reuse this check.

I also agree with @tomleb3 's answer. Flattening them into one state will make sure you don't get multiple rerenders.